# голосовой ассистент с NLP python

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, распознавание-речи, nlp

Я не ML engineering, я программист, но мне хочется сделать своего голосового ассистента. Если speech recognition сейчас не проблема, то nlp для меня остаётся загадкой. Например, голосовой ассистент задаёт пользователю вопрос: "Включить ли музыку?" - я хочу, чтобы бот классифицировал ответ пользователя к двум классам: да, нет.
Пользователь может сказать: "Давай включай" или "Угу", или ещё что-то. Я хочу чтобы, голосовой ассистент вне зависимости от фразы знал, включать ли ему музыку или нет.
Как это сделать?
Спасибо. Своим ответом вы мне очень сильно поможете.

UPD

**Хоть я и не проффисионал в области ML. Я могу создавать нейросети используя tensorflow. Не надо думать что я жду от вас какую-то волшебную функцию которая решит все мои проблемы.**

Comment: Давайте уточним вопрос.  Вы хотите, что бы вам тут, в ответе на форуме, в несколько строк описали то, как самому создать нейросеть для распознавания голоса и классификации ответа? Или вы хотите, что-бы вам сказали - "вызови вот эту функцию и она сотворит то, что тебе надо"?  И еще -  не кажется ли вам, что вот эта фраза абсолютно лишена смысла: "Я хочу чтобы, голосовой ассистент вне зависимости от фразы знал, включать ли ему музыку или нет". Как он может что-то знать, что не зависит от фразы ответа???   Мысли что-ли читать? Разъясните вашу мысль.

Comment: @passant, с speech recognition я разберусь сам. Что касается моей фразы, я хочу чтобы бот понимал что "Давай включай", "Ок, попробуй", "Ладно", "Так уж и быть"...=Да, а "Не", "Ненадо"... =Нет

Comment: Единственное что я хочу получить в ответе на этот вопрос, это описание того,  как сделать нейронную сеть которая могла бы классифицировать ответ пользователя к классам(да, нет). Может код

Comment: А , ну это просто. Сначала запускаете сеть, способную распознать голосовое сообщение и превратить его в фразу (например - вот так https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/postroenie-i-obuchenie-neyronnoy-seti-dlya-resheniya-zadachi-raspoznavaniya-rechi/viewer), а потом выходы этой нейросети подаете на вход элементарного, предаврительно обученного классификатора. В вашем случае - бинарного.

Comment: Я вообще в этом не специалист, но мне кажется что проще может быть просто перебрать все возможные фразы, которые могут означать положительный или отрицательный ответы, вряд ли их будет так уж много

Comment: @passant, всё до этой фразы(а потом выходы этой нейросети подаете на вход элементарного, предаврительно обученного классификатора. В вашем случае - бинарного) вашего ответа я понял, а после - нет. Как сделать этот классификатор? На чём его учить? Как его учить(насколько я знаю, компьютер не работает с текстом, текст нужно как-то во что-то преобразовать.)? Пожалуйста, можно по подробнее про этот классификатор?.

Comment: Вот тут подробно обо всех аспектах вашей задачи https://www.kdnuggets.com/2020/07/5-fantastic-nlp-books.html  А вот тут - о распознавании речи  https://stackabuse.com/introduction-to-speech-recognition-with-python/ Ну и исключительно классификация текста https://towardsdatascience.com/text-classification-with-pytorch-7111dae111a6 и https://towardsdatascience.com/text-classification-with-nlp-tf-idf-vs-word2vec-vs-bert-41ff868d1794

Comment: Спасибо. Когда изучу материал подробнее, отпишу решило ли это мою проблему.

Comment: Выделять спектры из движущегося окошка по Фурье образу голоса,как то это подавать на сеть,на ютуб англоязычные уроки видел.

Comment: @passant, вторая статья невероятно интересная и это как раз то, что мне нужно. В особенности мне понравился материал про bert. Но, эта статья 2018 года, есть что нибудь по свежее про bert(посвежее, но тематика статьи должна быть такая же: Классификация текстов). Просто, я думаю, что за 2 года bert сильно обновили(конечно же, в лучшую сторону).

Comment: @kali_xyyali А самому найти хоть что-то -  слабо? Вы же "программист" (по крайней мере сами себя так называете), неужели Гууглом пользоваться не умеете? Так бывает? Тем более, что все!!! (тема, ключевые слова, авторы...) для поиска у вас есть. Но нет, ждете, что бы кто-то это сделал за вас.  Подсказка - да за два года появилось очень много чего нового и интересного. Ищите.

Comment: @passant, умничка, спасибо за добрые слова. Пожалуйста, прочитай эти комментарии до конца, может поймёшь что так нельзя делать. У меня есть один друг, он мне постоянно присылает тупые вопросы. Как-то у него не работал класс, я дописал пару методов, и прислал его(класс) ему(другу). Он почему-то не захотел делать копи-пасту, он попросил прислать ему весь код в архиве(проект был не маленький, но я это сделал, прислал ему весь код в архиве).

Comment: Я никогда ему(или кому-то другому) не присылал такие вещи("оскорбления"):  "А самому найти хоть что-то - слабо? Вы же "программист" (по крайней мере сами себя так называете), неужели Гууглом пользоваться не умеете? Так бывает?"

Comment: Был ещё один случай, ещё один друг(он ещё совсем beginner) написал полный бред в коде, я не говорил ему что он дебил, я просто исправил код, и скинул ссылку на нужный туториал.** Если я не гуглю материал сам, на это есть причины. Я full-stack разработчик, не ML engineer, я работаю в стартапе 10 часов в день. Мне просто хочется прийти и выспаться. Тем более эта тема(nlp) не так легко гуглится,  даже если я найду туториал, как мне знать, что это то, что мне нужно? Методом проб и ошибок(читать и переводить каждый туториал), у меня на это времени нет.**

Comment: @kali_xyyali  Я понял, вы занятый благородный full-stack разработчик, работающий аж по 10 часов в день, а остальные -  ленивые бездельники, у которых   25 свободных часа в сутки что-бы "читать и переводить туториал" нужный для вас.  Или искать за вас то, что нужно вам в Гуугле.  Просто потому, что вам хочется выспаться.  Удачи и приятных снов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот [ссылка](https://neurohive.io/ru/tutorial/bert-klassifikacya-teksta/) на статью, там всё подробно расписано. Если надо, дам ёщё.

UPD
Используйте обучение с подкреплением.

Comment: Приведите основные тезисы из статьи прямо в ответе. Если ссылка станет недействительной, то ответ не будет иметь смысла